# If an app works on the iPad 2 is it necessary to test it on the iPad mini?

Tags: ios, ipad, testing

It may seem like you would always want to test your app on all devices that Apple offers: the iPad 2, iPad mini, and iPad 4. But its expensive or difficult to obtain all three devices and keep them around just for testing.

The iPad 2 and mini both have 512MB DDR2, use the 1GHz dual core A9, a Dual-core PowerVR SGX543MP2 and have the same screen resolution. It seems like its the same hardware all together.

Is there likely to be any difference between these two devices that could cause a problem with an app, other than the obvious physically smaller screen size?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it depends on what the app is. Like you said, screen size is different, but that may have a small effect on the usability of the app.

Other than that, I don't know. Sorry.